# MySQL query optimisation

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index, innodb, update

This is the MySQL table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `username` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `jid` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nick` text NOT NULL,
  `subscription` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `ask` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `askmessage` text NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `val` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `i_rosteru_val_val2_jid` (`val`,`username`,`jid`),
  KEY `i_rosteru_jid` (`jid`),
  KEY `i_rosteru_val_val2` (`val`,`username`)
)
```

the table has 20000000 records,

when I update the column with this query:

```
update users 
set jid = REPLACE(jid, 'chat.com', 'p.com')
limit 10000;
```

this table is doing a full scan, thus getting a slow response for the update query.

how to modify the query or modify the column to add an index? if I do add an index, will the index creation also take a lot of time because of the records?

**MySQL Ver 8.0.32**

Comment: Is "chat.com" always at the beginning of `jid`?

Comment: @RickJames, Yes

Answer (score 1):

To speed the query up a little bit you could add a where clause based on your comment

> Is "chat.com" always at the beginning of jid? Yes

The `jid` column is already indexed and the following query would lookup only the values starting with chat.com.

```
update users 
set jid = REPLACE(jid, 'chat.com', 'p.com')
where jid like 'chat.com%'
limit 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not sorting, so there's no way an index can help `LIMIT`. Your query is just using applying the update to the first 1000 rows that are read, as the table is scanned.

MySQL does quit examining rows once it has read enough to satisfy the `LIMIT`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html which says:

> As soon as MySQL has sent the required number of rows to the client, it aborts the query unless you are using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

I assume this also applies to `UPDATE`, which does not send a result set, but I would think it behaves similarly, stopping the query once it has changed enough rows. But as I think about it, I don't know that for a fact.

What is true for `SELECT` or other statements, is that `EXPLAIN` will report a table-scan and report the full number of rows in the table in the `rows` field of the `EXPLAIN` report. This doesn't necessarily mean it will examine *all* of those rows. It means it *may* have to examine that many rows before it finds enough to fill the `LIMIT` criteria, if your query has any conditions.

So don't trust `EXPLAIN` to tell you that it will actually examine all rows of a table.

An alternative way to measure the read number of rows examined is with `SHOW SESSION STATUS`.

I created a table like yours and filled it with a half million rows. Then I tried your `UPDATE...LIMIT` and measured the number of rows it examined:

```
mysql> flush status;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update users 
    -> set jid = REPLACE(jid, 'chat.com', 'p.com')
    -> limit 10000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 10000  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show session status like 'handler%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 2     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 1     |
| Handler_read_key           | 10001 |
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 9999  |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 10000 |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 0     |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 0     |
+----------------------------+-------+
```

The "Handler" status variables measure how many times the session has called into the storage engine interface, and we can see the number of calls is about the same number as the `LIMIT` I used, not the half-million rows I put in the table.

Comment: So is there no way to make the update query better? would a new index also not help?

Comment: Your query isn't searching or sorting. How could an index help?

Comment: I have read that an index also helps updating a table

Comment: If your UPDATE tries to reduce the set of examined rows with a condition in a WHERE clause, then yes, an index might help (if the condition is sargable). But the example you show doesn't have any WHERE clause. It will examine every row in the table regardless, so there's no benefit to adding an index.

Answer (score 0):

- `UPDATEing` a column in the `PRIMARY KEY` requires [essentially] deleting the row and inserting it somewhere else, plus updating all the indexes.
- What does `jid` look like?  If it is "chat.com" in many cases, then adding this to the query

  ```
    WHERE jid = 'chat.com'
  ```

would let it use the index and be much faster.

- If `jid` "begins with" that, then

  ```
    WHERE jid LIKE 'chat.com%'
  ```
- If `jid` looks like `foobar.chat.com`, that `WHERE` is useless and so is the index.
- That `UNIQUE` key will be promoted to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Because the `PRIMARY KEY` is so complex, it is not practical to first find the rows to change and then change just them.
- What is the concern?  The query takes a long time?  You can't afford for the table to be blocked for that "long time"?  Or can you simply start it on Friday night and hope if finished before Monday morning?
- If it crashes (due to, say, being out of disk space and it needs to `ROLLBACK`), it will take even longer to recover.
- Replacing your 3 keys with this would help the `UPDATE` and *might not* hurt other queries:

  ```
    PRIMARY KEY(jid, val, username)
    KEY `i_rosteru_val_val2` (`val`,`username`)  -- (as is)
  ```

  But doing the necessary `ALTER TABLE` would take some time.
- If a lot of rows need changing, this might be faster:

  ```
    CREATE TABLE users_new LIKE users;
    -- see ALTER1 below
    INSERT INTO users_new
            ( username, jid, nick, subscription, ask, askmessage, crated_at, val)
        SELECT  username, 
                REPLACE(jid, 'chat.com', 'p.com'),
                nick, subscription, ask, askmessage, crated_at, val)
            FROM users;
    -- see ALTER2 below
    RENAME TABLE users TO users_old,
                 users_new TO users;
    DROP TABLE users;
  ```
- You could do the suggested ALTER very efficiently via

  ```
    ALTER 1:  (on empty table == very fast)

        ALTER TABLE users_new
            DROP INDEX i_rosteru_val_val2_jid,
            DROP INDEX i_rosteru_jid,
            DROP INDEX i_rosteru_val_val2;
            ADD PRIMARY KEY(jid, val, username);

    ALTER 2:  (slow, but necessary)

        ALTER TABLE users_new
            ADD INDEX `i_rosteru_val_val2` (`val`,`username`);
  ```

  Note that the above technique does not block access to `users` while doing all the heavy lifting.

Comment: There is NO PRIMARY KEY in the posted CREATE TABLE info.